# can anyone know how change Kibana style?

Tags: plugins, styles, kibana, edit, wazuh

I wanna change the style of wazuh Kibana plugin I download source file from GitHub. and in source file which file I need to edit like I wanna change steps places like security, scan etc.??

Answer (score 1):

To modify the style of the wazuh app kibana plugin, you need to download the repo from this https://github.com/wazuh/wazuh-kibana-app.

Then, you can modify the files for each part of the dashboard you want to change, by modifying, inserting, or removing the code related to each visualization you may want to change.

The files are located inside the `public` folder.

You can also create custom visualizations from the Kibana Interface. Here's an example from the wazuh documentation:
https://documentation.wazuh.com/current/user-manual/kibana-app/reference/custom-dashboard.html

I hope this has been useful.